# CURL not working well with docker-compose, Elasticsearch and Windows 10

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, curl, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml file is listed below. This is what I want:

- Spin up an Elasticsearch instance through docker-compose
- Run a setup file in the container of the Elasticsearch image
- The setup file should be 'copied' from my host machine (so using volumes)

This is what I got so far:

```
version: '3'

services:
  b-elastic:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.1
    container_name: b-elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    volumes:
      - ./dockerelastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./:/project
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

I can verify that the setupfile is present:

```
$ docker exec -it b-elastic vi /project/database/elasticsearch/setup.json
```

gives:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "max_ngram_diff": "3"
        },
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "username_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "username_tokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "username_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": "1",
                    "max_gram": "4"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "_all" : { "enabled" : false },
            "username": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "username_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to execute the setup.json on Elasticsearch:

```
$ docker exec -it b-elastic curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/users -H  "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @project/database/elasticsearch/setup.json
```

This is what Docker returns:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file
Warning: "project/database/elasticsearch/setup.json", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.
{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true,"index":"users"}
```

It looks like it is acknowledged, but when I try to search for users, I get this error:

```
[match] analyzer [username_analyzer] not found
```

I don't get this error when copy paste the contents of setup.json in Postman and execute the request there.

How can I execute a file through a volume in an Elasticsearch container on Windows?

Edit: The accepted answer works, but note that it failed for me when executing the command with PowerShell. Command Prompt worked.

Comment: looks like curl is not able to read the file you are sending. Is the file part of the container? Also use `@/project` instead of `@project` to give the absolute path, since your entrypoint might not be `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like curl wasn't able to read your setup.json file, so it created an empty index.
Notice that when you are using vi, you are using the absolute path (/ in the start), but when you are using curl you didn't. Try

`docker exec -it b-elastic curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/users -H  "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @/project/database/elasticsearch/setup.json`

This instead and see if it works

Comment: Thanks! I already tried that, but I got this error: No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the end of the line. Turns out that is just a PowerShell thing. When I executed this line of code in regular Command Prompt, things are working! Thanks again!